# Unable to send or recive emails from localhost using php or mercury32

Tags: php, windows, apache, email, xampp

```
C:\xampp\sendmail.ini :

smtp_server=localhost
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=tls
error_logfile=error.log
auth_username=munish259272@gmail.com
auth_password=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
force_sender=munish259272@gmail.com


c:\xampp\php.ini
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
;sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

I have applied the setting in mercury32 and ini files from this website
[http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/Mercury_Mail_Configuration_in_Windows](http://www.open-[image]emr.org/wiki/index.php/Mercury_Mail_Configuration_in_Windows)

this is what the mercury window shows.

Comment: There's so much more to it than this. Seeing your code would be a good start.

Comment: even the simple code `<?php
mail('munish259272@gmail.com','sample mail','sample content');

?>` does not work

Comment: has Mercury been setup to allow local relay of messages to remote sites?

Comment: Since you accidentally posted your password I noticed that you have two-factor authentication (I had no ill-intent), which however means that simple username/password will not work (it would be circumventing the secure two-factor). I think that you need to setup app password https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: Thanks a lot peter. you solved my problem i was struggling for very long with this.Also i changed my password since it may be viewed by someone else.